# psycopg2.ProgrammingError, running script to serialize data of django app from postgres

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a `djano web app` which stores the data about some entries to `postgres db`.To copy the data in db to `json file`s ,I generally use the `python manage.py shell` and use the serialization api as mentioned i django tutorial.

```
>>>python manage.py shell
...
In[8]:from myapp.models import MyFirstModel
In[9]:data = serializers.serialize("xml", MyFirstModel.objects.all())
In[10]:print data
```

I copy this output to some text file and save it as json.

I thought of writing a script to do this and tried

datacopy.py
........

```
...
filename = os.path.join(dirpath,basefilename+".json")

def write_data_to_file():
    from django.core import serializers
    XMLSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
    xml_serializer = XMLSerializer()
    out = open(filename,"a")
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from myapp.models import MyFirstModel
    from myapp.models import MyNextModel
    xml_serializer.serialize(User.objects.all(), stream=out)
    xml_serializer.serialize(MyFirstModel.objects.all(), stream=out)
    xml_serializer.serialize(MyNextModel.objects.all(), stream=out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_data_to_file()
```

From bash shell,I tried

```
>>python datacopy.py
```

But, this writes only the User model's data and fails to copy the models which I create in my app.

The error message I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datacopy.py", line 29, in <module>
    write_data_to_file()
  File "datacopy.py", line 23, in write_data_to_file
    xml_serializer.serialize(MyFirstModel.objects.all(), stream=out)
  File "/home/me/Django-1.1.1/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 38, in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/home/me/Django-1.1.1/django/db/models/query.py", line 106, in _result_iter
    self._fill_cache()
  File "/home/me/Django-1.1.1/django/db/models/query.py", line 692, in _fill_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
  File "/home/me/Django-1.1.1/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    for row in self.query.results_iter():
  File "/home/me/Django-1.1.1/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 287, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/me/Django-1.1.1/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2369, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/me/Django-1.1.1/django/db/backends/util.py", line 19, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "myapp_myfirstmodel" does not exist
```

I am able to copy data of all three models when I use the `python manage.py shell`.Why does this error happen when I run the script from bash?I have the modules of myapp in PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in to using ./manage.py dumpdata ? You can specify the serialization format.

For your script to work have you set DJANGO_SETTINGS to the correct settings.py ?

Secondly is there a reason that you are doing your imports inside the function, probably better to move them to the head of the file:

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import MyFirstModel
from myapp.models import MyNextModel

def write_data_to_file():
    XMLSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
    xml_serializer = XMLSerializer()
    out = open(filename,"a")
```

Comment: I think it is because of DJANGO_SETTINGS ..thanks for reminding